# SIGFPE with std unordered map

Tags: c++, linker, c++14, std, unordered-map

Below is a simple application which causes SIGFPE for me if i uncomment the mentioned line in the main.cc.

config.h

```
#ifndef SRC_CONFIG_H_
#define SRC_CONFIG_H_

#include <cstdint>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using ConfigTable_t = std::unordered_map<uint16_t, std::tuple<std::string, std::vector<uint8_t> > >;

static const ConfigTable_t gTable1 {
  { 0x100, std::make_tuple( "table1", std::vector<uint8_t> { 5,5,5,5,5,5 } ) }
};

static const ConfigTable_t gTable2 {
  { 0x200, std::make_tuple( "table2", std::vector<uint8_t> { 0,1,2,3,4,5 } ) }
};

const ConfigTable_t & getConfigTable();

#endif
```

table_provider.cc

```
#include "config.h"

const ConfigTable_t & getConfigTable() {
    return gTable1;
}
```

main.cc

```
#include "config.h"

static const uint16_t gId = 0x100;
// static const std::string gName = std::get<0>(getConfigTable().at(gId)); //  <-- Doesn't work
static const std::string gName = std::get<0>(gTable1.at(gId));             //  <-- Works  

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

There was a pointer related to this issue in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36406774/3884862 but I could not figure out why it is happening.

I compile it with

> g++ -std=c++14 main.cc table_provider.cc -o test

g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

Don't put the definitions in the *header* file as that will lead to each [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) will have their own copy of the variables defined in the header file.

That means the `gTable1` returned by `getConfigTable` will be different from the `gTable1` defined in the `main.cc` file. And that other `gTable1` might not have been initialized when you use it.

The solution is to put the global variables in a *single* translation unit (source file). Or better yet, don't have global variables at all.

Answer (score 1):

This code suffers from [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/static-init-order.html). `gTable1` in `table_provider.cc` translation unit may be not initialized when you initialize `gName` in `main.cc` translation unit. Note that since `gTable1` is a `static` variable declared in header file each translation unit will have a separate instance. So accessing it directly and using `getConfigTable` will refer to different objects.